# Is it normal practice to use just one mutex to synchronize more than one resource?

Tags: synchronization, locking, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

I'am writing an application which is used pthread mutex. There are parts which is responsible to different jobs, one part for writing to file (file descriptor resource), second for working with queue (queue variable), third to working with timer (timer variable), etc. From this point of view is it correct to use the different mutexes for different jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear **Mutex-:** "Mutexes are typically used to serialise access to a section of re-entrant code that cannot be executed concurrently by more than one thread. A mutex object only allows one thread into a controlled section, forcing other threads which attempt to gain access to that section to wait until the first thread has exited from that section."

> Is it normal practice to use just one mutex to synchronize more than
>   one resource?

It's totally depends on your application. If these resources are dependent and you can't execute it parallel then it's normal.

> From this point of view is it correct to use the different mutexes for
>   different jobs?

Yes you should use different mutex, so you can do concurrently different task. Because in this case jobs are different from each other.